# Send button press from Android app to Raspberry Pi over Wi-Fi

Tags: java, android, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I need a way to send a button press from an Android App to a Raspberry Pi Model B, over Wi-Fi. This is to control a remote vehicle.

I know the App needs to be written in Java, and the receiving end needs to be in Python.

Thanks

Comment: No the app does not have to been written in java. And the pi does not have to be programmed in python.

Comment: This is specified in my project specifications, so they do have to be programmed in those languages

Comment: Well then you are lucky as you can find ready code on many places on the internet. Basic stuff.

Comment: I can't find anything on how to send a button press, could you possibly point me in the right direction, possibly give me a webpage to look at? Thanks